# Stuck at login screen

Tags: world-of-warcraft

When I login in World of Warcraft, I just get the "Success!" message, when I click on "cancel" the realm selection screen comes up, but when I try to login on any realm I just get the message "Logging in to game server" and this don't changes even after a few minutes (most of the time sometimes I can login after a while). What should I do to fix this?

Comment: You'll get better support if you go to the warcraft forums and post this specific question. If you're experiencing a problem that many users are also experiencing then you'll doubtless find posts of a similar nature (and hopefully with a "blue" response from a GM). If it's a problem specific to just you then you're also a lot more likely to get a useful answer. Now, all of that being said, when I've had this problem in the past it's usually because one of the many servers is down (the world server or the character server or the login/authentication server).

Comment: Is this beta, test or live? Which server? When did this start happening? You'd have to include a lot more details if you are to post this on Blizzard's website.

Comment: Most likely this is happening to you on a Tuesday, which after checking my calendar the day this was asked was in fact a Tuesday. Tuesday's are notoriously server maintenance days and WoW is typically down for at least 8 hours every Tuesday of every week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this happens often it could be a local problem, try reinstalling WoW or deleting your WTF folder.
If not the server could be under maintenance or blizzard could be having some other problem before. I've had this problem before also and it usually goes away with time.

Comment: Deleting the WTF folder made it normal again, thank you.

Comment: I always find it funny that the WTF folder is usually the source of so many "WTF!?!?" moments with WoW. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

1. Repair tool on patcher
2. Deleting Battle.net files then repair tool (not sure if will just mess the game up though, seems to half the time)
3. Reinstalling WoW

Remember: If you need to install do so after backing up all of your addons, or at least writing them down.